# Changing from has_many to has_one relation rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, nested-forms

Here personaldetails belongs_to user and the relation given is has_many which is wrong.I want to convert the has_many relation to has_one relation i.e. User has_one personaldetails. When I change the relation directly I am getting an error "uninitialized constant User::Personaldetails. Please guide me how to convert the relation .

Personaldetail.rb

```
class Personaldetail < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :personaldetails, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :personaldetails, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

routes.rb

```
 resources :users, except: [:new] do
  resources :personaldetails
 end
```

user_steps_controller.rb

```
class UserStepsController < ApplicationController
    include Wicked::Wizard
    steps : :personaldetails
    def show
        @user = current_user
        @personaldetails = @user.personaldetails.build
        render_wizard
    end

def update
    @user = current_user
    @user.update!(user_params)
    render_wizard @user
end
   
private

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :password, :password_confirmation, :user_id,
      personaldetails_attributes: [:id,:first_name, :last_name, :gmail, :mobile_no, :city, :state, :pin_code, :_destroy])
end
end
```

personaldetails.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: @user, url: wizard_path, local: true) do |form| %> 
  <%= form.fields_for :personaldetail,Personaldetail.new do |info| %>
    <%= render 'personaldetails_field', form: info %>
  <% end %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

_personaldetails_field.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
<%= form.label :First_name %><br />
<%= form.text_field :first_name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= form.label :Last_name %><br />
<%= form.text_field :last_name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= form.label :email %><br />
<%= form.text_field :gmail %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= form.label :Mobile_number %><br />
<%= form.text_field :mobile_no %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= form.label :City %><br />
<%= form.text_field :city %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= form.label :State %><br />
<%= form.text_field :state %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= form.label :Pincode %><br />
<%= form.text_field :pin_code %>
</div>
```

So the solution is:

Personaldetail.rb

```
class Personaldetail < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_one :personaldetails, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :personaldetails, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

routes.rb

```
 resources :users, except: [:new] do
  resources :personaldetail
 end
```

user_steps_controller.rb

```
class UserStepsController < ApplicationController
    include Wicked::Wizard
    steps : :personaldetails
    def show
        @user = current_user
        render_wizard
    end

def update
    @user = current_user
    @user.update!(user_params)
    render_wizard @user
end
   
private

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :password, :password_confirmation, :user_id,
      personaldetails_attributes: [:id,:first_name, :last_name, :gmail, :mobile_no, :city, :state, :pin_code, :_destroy])
end
end
```

personaldetail.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: @user, url: wizard_path, local: true) do |form| %> 
  <%= form.fields_for :personaldetail,@user.personaldetail || @user.build_personaldetail do |info| %>
    <%= render 'personaldetail_field', form: info %>
  <% end %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

_personaldetail_field.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
<%= form.label :First_name %><br />
<%= form.text_field :first_name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= form.label :Last_name %><br />
<%= form.text_field :last_name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= form.label :email %><br />
<%= form.text_field :gmail %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= form.label :Mobile_number %><br />
<%= form.text_field :mobile_no %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= form.label :City %><br />
<%= form.text_field :city %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= form.label :State %><br />
<%= form.text_field :state %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= form.label :Pincode %><br />
<%= form.text_field :pin_code %>
</div>
```

Comment: Rails naming conventions expect `has_one` to be in the singular. That means at every place in code in which you refer to a `personal_details` array you now need to refer directly to a `personal_detail` instance.

Comment: So will it now be @user.personaldetail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comment by spickermann,  `has_many` relationship wants plural form and `has_one` the singular form.
That is to say, you should already be able to infer the relationship from:

```
@user.personaldetails # user has many personal details
@user.personaldetail  # user has one personal detail
```

Just a consideration: many weird cases arise when objects/models are not properly named. As a rule of thumb, you should use the most fitting and precise English noun for the object you need to name. That will help you hugely in cases like this. In normal English language, it is somehow strange to say "a user has a personal detail" but you would say of course "has personal details". Particularly when it comes to ActiveRecord associations, Rails syntax should be the nearest as possible to English language, to avoid later misunderstandings.  I guess this confusion would not have arisen if instead of "PersonalDetail", the model was called "Account" or "Profile", for instance.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, I actually have one doubt if I use has_one and create a personaldetail object and then create another new object of personaldetail will the new object replace the old object?

Comment: Try that in the rails console and see what happens. Error messages will be your best friends to help you understand how ActiveRecord relationships work :)

Comment: Yup i tried it and I did not get an error. I actually thought I will get an error

Comment: Thank you for the advice yup u are right we should have named it profile or account.

Comment: You're welcome - assuming that the personaldetail object is for the same user - just check the user.personaldetail and see which of the two you created is shown :)

Answer (score 2):

try with: `has_one :personaldetail, dependent: :destroy`
Rails are guessing class name from name AND type of association, so with has_many they will try to singularize association name (personaldetails => Personaldetail) but with has_one they will try to reach it as is (personaldetails => Personaldetails)

Comment: Im afraid I did not understand it completely. Can you please elaborate a little

Answer (score 1):

Few suggestions/comments

1. Keep model name as CamelCase like `PersonalDetail` rather than `Personaldetail` and association name `has_one :personal_detail`
2. Using `has_one` relation you can create the object using `user.build_personal_detail.save`
3. When you run the 2nd step again it will create another record in `personal_details` table and in that transaction it will return the new record. But, after that when you try to query it will return the 1st created personal_details record rather than new one. That's because `ActiveRecord` by default sorts by id and limit 1 for `has_one` relation